# would golang-protobuf@v1.3.2 cause memory leak in golang 1.12 version?

Tags: go, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, runtime, protocol-buffers

heap svg use go pprof:

[image: heap svg use go pprof]

top10 use go pprof:

[image: top10 use go pprof]

1. golang version: 1.12
2. golang-protobuf: 1.3.2
3. operating system：2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64
4. When I deploy the code to the environment, the server's memory has been soaring.
5. When I use runtime.GC once every 1000 cycle inside the function, the memory will not rise.

like this:

```
index = 1

func xxx(){
...
    if index%1000 == 0{
        runtime.GC()
    }
...
}
```

Comment: it seems your pictures are showing allocations. Which is not memory leaks, yet. In go, memory leaks are values maintained in memory by a resource. typically, a giant slice remains in memory because it is being referenced by a goroutine that wont quit. Calling runtime.GC only force a memory cleanup ASAP. You have not provided evidences of memory leaks, in facts.

Comment: Maybe I didn't accurately describe my problem. 
I mean, it has been rising continuously. After half an hour, the program has risen to 20G, and then continues to rise.

Comment: If this is a matter of GC, you want to look at the `gctrace` output to see how it's collecting and what the targets are. Theoretically if running `runtime.GC()` fixes it, it will eventually level out. Otherwise, tweaking `GOGC` may improve performance. Actual "memory leaks" (which this isn't if calling GC manually fixes it) really require leaking goroutines, which are easy to spot in a stack trace, or unsafe memory handling.